# Return .cells range in Excel formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a script to find the appropriate column and create a formula with that cells "name" in it. This is the script:

```
'Search for value
Dim i As Integer
i = 4
    Do Until Cells(9, i).Value = ddLeveranciers.Value Or Cells(9, i).Value = ""
        i = i + 1
    Loop

'Add formulas
Range("D5").Formula = "=IF(" & Cells(15, i) & "<>"""",D4*" & Cells(15, i) & ","""")"
```

This now returns the formula `"=IF(1.23<>"",D4*1.23,"")"`, `1.23` being the value of `cells(15,i)`. I would like the script to return (for example) **`"=IF(D15<>"",D4*D15,"")"`**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.Address`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) property.

```
Range("D5").Formula = "=IF(" & Cells(15, i).Address & "<>"""",D4*" & Cells(15, i).Address & ","""")"
```

**For example:**

`MsgBox(Cells(1,1).Address)`

Would return `$A$1`

Comment: Yes! That works! I knew I was almost there, but I didn't know the .Address property. Thanks!

Comment: I'll accept your question in some minutes. There is a time lock and you were too fast :p

Comment: No problem - glad it helped!